# Правильно ли я делаю поиск php+mysql?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Вообщем нужно сделать поиск по записям бд . Есть select элемент , опциями которого являются названия полей таблицы и input элемент с сообственно строкой поиска

```html
<div>
  <select id="searchBy" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border: 1px solid #d2d6de;font-size: initial; padding: 0px 10px;">
    <option value="">Selectionner une colonne ...</option>
    <option value="id">id</option>
    <option value="agence">Réceptif</option>
    <option value="signature">Nom et Prénom du signataire</option>
    <option value="email">Mail de contact</option>
    <option value="website">Site internet</option>
    <option value="support_user">Nom et prénom - support</option>
    <option value="support_email">Mail - support</option>
    <option value="pays">pays</option>
    <option value="adress1">Adresse 1</option>
    <option value="adress2">Adresse 2</option>
    <option value="ville">Ville</option>
    <option value="zip">Code postal</option>
    <option value="telephone">Téléphone</option>
    <option value="fax">Fax</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- /btn-group -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchKey" style="font-size: initial;" placeholder="" value="">
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-info btn-flat startSearch">Rechercher</button>
</span>
```

Подскажите правильно ли я мыслю .
Сначала ajax запросом через get метод передаю на сервер значение того инпута и селекта . В браузере получается что-то этого http://test?name=people&key=vasya;
Потом нужно в зависимости от этих данных сформировать sql запрос . Здесь нужен ваш совет как правильно его сформировать. 
Так вот выглядит запрос сейчас

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM receptifs ORDER BY $sort $type");
```

Допустим , у меня есть значения

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$key = $_GET['key'];
```

тогда составляем запрос

```
$sql = "WHERE $name LIKE ?";
```

И тогда подставляем это к предыдущему запросу

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * SELECT * FROM receptifs $sql ORDER BY $sort $type");
$stm->execute(array($key));
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Правильный ли такой подход ? прошу не обращать внимания на детали реализации ( прямой доступ к гет и т.д) . нужно знать просто имеет ли смысл такой способ или как-то по-другому лучше с делать?

Comment: У вас в таблице какие поля есть? Что вы хотите выбрать?

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете `prepare`.  `$a = $pdo->repare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?"); $a->bindValue(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR); $a->execute();`. Ваш вариант не защишен от SQL injection.

Comment: В таблице поля - это значения этих опций . Хочу выбрать записи , в которых искомое значение встречается в соответствующих полях

Comment: sphinx вам в помощь